# How to change bootstrap4 navbar search box button margin padding?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As you can see the attached image, bootstrap4 navbar search box and 'search button' does not have gap or margin in between when browser resized. I was reading solution on the documentation but could not figure out. How Can I create custom margin to create gap for search button?

[image]

Comment: Please share some code from your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use **margin** property. 
You can find more here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: I mentioned about margin  property in my question description. I need to know where to set the margin? under which class / div / section ? how?

Comment: `.form-control{
  margin-bottom:10px;
} ` try this

Comment: this is because search button has size classes " my-2 my-sm-0 "  so if you need to use margin property remove these classes or just edit another element.